# Access Form Wizard for Two Simple Subforms

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2013, I can't use the Form Wizard to add two subforms. Well, the wizard, to be exact, skips the 'choose the main form' step, and upon completion fails to display the main form, only the header. I've replicated this on another computer.

For example, see 3 tables...

First called 'Users' with an ID (PK) and a 'Full name' field.

Second called 'Music' with an ID(PK), a UserID(Number) and 'Song' field.

Third called 'Movies' with an ID(PK), a UserID(Number) and a 'Movie' field.

The relationships are linking the ID of the Users table to UserID of the Music and Movies tables. All very simple. Distilled to its most simple form.

I use the Form Wizard to add 2 fields to show the 'Full Name' of the Users table and the 'Song' field of the Music table, then all is well, and the wizard produces a workable, if unsightly, Form.

Adding the 'Movie' field on top of the 'Song' field (accessing two other linked tables instead of one) means that the next step, choosing the main form, is skipped and the resulting form is empty is User mode but shows fields (no subforms) in Design mode.

Is this a bug in Access or I'm doing it wrong?

Thank you for you time.

Here's a link to some screenshots and database I made for you (It's a OneDrive shared folder). http://1drv.ms/1yrZyvt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is exclusively by relation between tables.
You connect USERS to MUSIC and MOVIES for 1 to 1, in this case you need almost one register to see information... and can't add any new in one of other tables.
If you modify the relation and main select of the form, the you can run normally.
Put this on the form and you can see that run perfect:
SELECT Users.FullName, Music.Song, Movies.Movie
FROM (Users LEFT JOIN Music ON Users.[ID] = Music.[UserID]) LEFT JOIN Movies ON Users.[ID] = Movies.[UserID];

Some help for this configuration:

- Do relationship on tool.. not on every form. It's more easy to maintain
- Do always relations based on main registry (normally 1 to many)
- When insert any form into another, you can decide how to see and which field maintain the relation between.

Good luck

Comment: Hey MasterCafe! Thank you for your time and your answer. It's appreciated. :) I will now research how to have a subform for the movies and a subform for the songs.

Comment: Please confirm if this for other users, and value it ;-)